# Upload files with showing determinate Progress Bar in Notification bar using React Native

Tags: react-native, file-upload, notifications, progress-bar, android-notifications

I am trying to achieve a scenario where file is uploading and I want to make this upload process keep running with having percentage bar when the app was kill. And The process will resume upload process when the phone off with any reason (battery drain or out services).
I have tried this with local notification with Firebase and react-native-local-notifications. But it is not working.

Comment: Could you please elaborate little more. I could understand only some of your question.

Comment: Actually I am uploading files to server and showing progress in Percentage in  Progress Bar. But Now I want show the Progress in Notification Area.

Comment: Got your question now @Pankaj Negi !. Thnx.

Comment: do you know about this scenario ?? how can we do this in React Native ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, there is no library which uploads files with notification progress bar even the app is cancelled. So Have to create Native Component in Android Native then used that library in your react-native project. thanks :)

Comment: How you achieved this?

Answer (score 2):

Test this package out,

[react-native background-upload](https://github.com/Vydia/react-native-background-upload)

Hope this helps you, do comment if any doubts.

Comment: yes I have tired this. But how to display progress in notification bar when I get progress in  Upload.addListener('progress', uploadId, (data) => {
    console.log(`Progress: ${data.progress}%`)
  }). ??

Comment: @PankajNegi use notification:true for android